# Fabric, how to associate crash with events?

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I see Crashes and Events for my iOS app on the Fabric dashboard.  However, there does not seem to be a way to put the two together.  For instance, if I am looking at a crash, I want to see the "events" that occurred with that crash report.  It would help me to reproduce the crash.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Todd from Fabric here - there isn't a way to combine Answers and Crashlytics data. However we allow up to 64kb of logs and key:value pairs with each crash session. Check out this page for details: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html